# Revert from Windows 7 Basic Theme

Tags: windows-7, themes

I got a message from Windows 7 that alerted me that my computer was being slow and I allowed it to change my theme to Windows 7 Basic Theme.

I am very much regretting my decision because my computer looks very bad and i just want to turn this theme off - I want to customize the system color, theme, etc...

How do I do this?

Comment: You mean you want to disable that alert notification suggestion forever, or you simply want to change the theme to aero?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Personalization > Select the theme you want (I think you're looking for 'Windows 7' under 'Aero Themes'.

[image]